# Character rotation stuttering over network (using photon)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm making a simple multiplayer game in unity.

I have a networkcharacter script but only the rotation seems to not be working. The character that i receive over the network simply falls down flat on the ground an begins stuttering up and down. All the other things (movement, animators) work just fine. Here is my NetworkCharacter script:

```
public class NetworkCharacter : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{
 private Vector3 correctPlayerPos;
 private Quaternion correctPlayerRot;
 private Animator anim;
 private float correctForward;
 private float correctTurn;
 private float correctJump;
 private float correctJumpLeg;
 private bool correctCrouch;
 private bool correctOnGround;

 void Start()
 {
     anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (!photonView.isMine)
     {
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, this.correctPlayerPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);

         try { 
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, this.correctPlayerRot, Time.deltaTime * 5);
         } catch(Exception e)
         {
             print(e.Message);
         }
         anim.SetFloat("Forward", Mathf.Lerp(anim.GetFloat("Forward"), correctForward, Time.deltaTime * 5));
         anim.SetFloat("Turn", Mathf.Lerp(anim.GetFloat("Turn"), correctTurn, Time.deltaTime * 5));
         anim.SetFloat("Jump", Mathf.Lerp(anim.GetFloat("Jump"), correctJump, Time.deltaTime * 5));
         anim.SetFloat("JumpLeg", Mathf.Lerp(anim.GetFloat("JumpLeg"), correctJumpLeg, Time.deltaTime * 5));

         anim.SetBool("Crouch", correctCrouch);
         anim.SetBool("OnGround", correctOnGround);
     }
 }

 void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
 {
     if (stream.isWriting)
     {
         // We own this player: send the others our data
         stream.SendNext(transform.position);
         stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetFloat("Forward"));
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetFloat("Turn"));
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetFloat("Jump"));
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetFloat("JumpLeg"));
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetBool("Crouch"));
         stream.SendNext(anim.GetBool("OnGround"));

     }
     else
     {

         // Network player, receive data
         this.correctPlayerPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
         this.correctPlayerRot = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctForward = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctTurn = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctJump = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctJumpLeg = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctCrouch = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
         correctOnGround = (bool)stream.ReceiveNext();
     }
 }
```

}

If needed I can try to make a video of how the character is behaving. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry what is the question?

Comment: It's a multiplayer game, when i start it up alone everything works just fine. But when another player enters the game, his character on MY version of the game is laying on the ground and stuttering up and down, his location and animations are correct, but his rotation is not. Same thing the other way around, my character on HIS version of the game is laying on the ground and stuttering.

Comment: I've made a video, i hope that will clarify my problem 
https://youtu.be/GaqoiIpM43E

Comment: "This video has been removed by the user. Sorry about that." Well, that was a short-lived resource.